# JavaScript Regex Match Index

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following little block of code to find an image source in a web page:

```
var reImg = [
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"image attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+(.*?)\" class=\"attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"full-size-gal'
];
var u = new RegExp(reImg.join('|'), 'i').exec(pageSource);
if (u) { 
  print(u);
}
```

I use an array to store the regexes because I may need to add more expressions later.  Also, the double-quotes are escaped because the code above will be stored in a JSON file.

Now, the variable u has the results in it, but I need to get the value of u[1] or u[3] or u[5] - basically the stuff within the parenthesis.  The problem is that I don't know which one matched.  How do I get just the source URL?

Comment: Long story short, you can't, not like that.  Javascript regex does not have a way to return that sort of thing. Other languages can sorta accomplish this with capture groups because they are capable of returning multi-dim arrays that break down what was matched by each captured group. JS doesn't do this, so basically you need to instead loop through `reImg` and `exec` them individually and return/break at first match

Comment: fyi it might be a slight performance increase to keep doing what you are doing now, but then match `u` against each eleme of `reImg` after the initial match (what you are doing now) so that you don't have to walk through all of `pageSource` for each regex

Comment: By the way, you don't need to escape the double quotes. When and if you stringify this object, that will be done for you.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: You can do a global match and go through each match's capturing group in JavaScript with RegExp.exec. You are probably talking about `String.match`, but even `String.match` works if you only match once.

Comment: @torazaburo: It's complicated... This bit of code is for a plugin called DownThemAll and there actually ends up being multiple levels of escapes required.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: I don't quite follow how I can match u back to the array of reImg?  Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Caynadian Not that it matters, but the backslashes have no effect here whatsoever. They do not go into the string. Try printing the string to see. The backslashes are consumed by the JS parser while it is parsing the string literal. The string you are defining is precisely the same whether or not you use the escapes. To verify this, type the following into your console: `'"a"' === '\"a\"'`, and you will see that the strings are strictly equal.

Comment: @torazaburo: I realize that, thanks... When it ends up in DownThemAll, it will actually be in a JSON file that looks something like this:  { "resolve": "var img1='src=\\\"(.*?)\\\" class=\\\"attachment-img-';" }  Because of how DownThemAll works, the double quote needs to be escaped so that it doesn't mess with the JSON structure and then the escape char itself has to be escaped so that it doesn't mess with DownThemAll, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the solution from @PaulS does work, it required me to have an ever expanding if statement as more regexs are added to the list.  Instead, I went with the suggestion by @CrayonViolent and used a for loop:

```
var reImg = [
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"image attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)-[0-9]+x[0-9]+(.*?)\" class=\"attachment-img-',
  'src=\"(.*?)\" class=\"full-size-gal'
];
for (var i=0;i<reImg.length;i++) {
  var u = new RegExp(reImg[i], 'i').exec(pageSource);
  if (u) { 
    print(u[1]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just *logical OR* them with `||`, the failed matches will be *undefined*, finish with `|| ''` for an empty string match (the only possible *falsy* outcome in a match)

```
var re = /(a)|(b)|(c)/,
    m  = re.exec('foo_b_foo');
m;            // ["b", undefined, "b", undefined]
m[1] || m[2] || m[3]; // "b"
```

Remember that no match found will still be `null` so this should be inside an `if` block

---

```
var x;
if (u) { 
    x = u[1] || u[3] || u[5] || '';
    // these may not be all the possibilities from the example posted
    // i.e. you didn't mention `u[2]` ?
}
```

Comment: that's not going to work as you expect. that's not how js regex returns things.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Please comment with an example of how _JavaScript's RegExp_ returns things different to how I've put in the comments of line 3 and 4 of my example? I ran this code in my console as I wrote it.

Comment: This would be less than ideal as it would require me to change the logic each time I add a new regex to the array.